# SQL Server 2019 - Pivot Result on multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Please check my query and let me know what to do to get the proper result as expected -
query:

```
With ChemReq (AmdCode, ItemCode, itemcode1, D1K,D2K,D3K,D1,D2,D3)
as
(SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT t.AmdCode, t.ItemCode, t.itemcode1, t.BomCode, t.Requirement, t.PDay, t.PDayQty FROM Temp_Chemical t  
) ChemReq
PIVOT (
  SUM(Requirement) FOR PDayQty
  IN (D1K, D2K, D3K)
) AS Req
PIVOT (
  max(bomcode) FOR PDay
  IN (D1, D2, D3)
) AS Req1
)
Select amdcode,itemcode,itemcode1,D1K,D2K,D3K,D1,D2,D3 from ChemReq  
Group By AmdCode, ItemCode, itemcode1, D1K,D2K,D3K,D1,D2,D3
GO
```

[image]

Comment: GROUP BY less columns. Use MAX() or MIN() to pick the only non-null values.

Comment: Split your PIVOTs into two separate CTE's and then join the two on the final SELECT

Comment: Honestly, just use conditional aggregation, rather than that restrictive `PIVOT` operator.